# cocoa: popover ,How do I hide away region？

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

```
-(IBAction)showInfoPopover:(id)sender{
    [[self popover] showRelativeToRect:[sender bounds] ofView:sender preferredEdge:NSMaxYEdge];

}
```

How do I hide away region？

Hide popover ，What event ?
Tanks！

[image]

Comment: What are you asking here? You're going to have to put in more effort to construct a helpful, valid question with enough information in it that people can use to help you out.

Comment: My English is very bad, I'm sorry not clearly described .

Comment: Maybe helps -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294976/how-to-make-action-to-close-nspopover

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Comment: I deleted my answer, since you apparently have found a solution that works for you. But you nonetheless should accept your own answer so that others know it's a resolved issue.